# Constructors static keyword use

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, static, output

I read so many definitions of keyword 'static' and I still find it very confusing. Output of this program should be :

1 2 1 2 3 4 1 1 2 3 4 8 7 6 5 1 2 6 5

I understand how global members are called,but when the program reaches the main and static D d;  I get all confused. Thank you in advance to anyone willing to explain!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct D {
  D() { cout << "1" << endl; }
  ~D() { cout << "5" << endl; }
};
class C {
public:
  D d;
  C() { cout << "2" << endl; }
  ~C() { cout << "6" << endl; }
};
struct B {
  C c;
  B() { cout << "3" << endl; }
  ~B() { cout << "7" << endl; }
};
struct A {
  B b;
  A() { cout << "4" << endl; }
  ~A() { cout << "8" << endl; }
};
extern A a;
C c;
int main() {
  static D d;
  A{};
  C{};
  return 0;
}
A a;
extern B b;
```

Comment: There are no global members in your code.   If you believe there is, that is probably one factor in your confusion.

Comment: I’m confused about what you’re confused about. You put what the output you expected but, what you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, [I'm getting](https://godbolt.org/z/7ThscGMYv)

```
1 2
1 2 3 4
1
1 2 3 4
8 7 6 5
1 2 6 5
5 8 7 6 5 6 5
```

I broke the output down in groups that correspond to paragraphs that follow.

First, the global variable `C c;` is constructed. This first constructs its member variable of type `D`, which prints `1`; then `C`'s constructor prints `2`. That's the first `1 2` accounted for.

Then, the global variable `A a;` is constructed. Even though the definition is after `main`, global variables are constructed before `main` is entered. This first constructs the member of type `B`, which in turn constructs a member of type `C`, which we already know prints `1 2`. Then `B`'s constructor prints `3` and finally `A`'s constructor prints `4`. This is the next `1 2 3 4` accounted for.

Then `main` runs, and it first constructs `static D d;`, which prints `1`.

Then the temporary `A{}` is constructed, which we already know prints `1 2 3 4`. Then this temporary is destroyed. Destructors always run in the reverse order of construction, hence `8 7 6 5`

Then the temporary `C{}` is constructed and immediately destroyed. We already know `C`'s construction prints `1 2`, and destruction prints `6 5`.

And finally, `main` exits, and the `static D d` and the two global variables are destroyed in the reverse order of construction. They printed `1 2   1 2 3 4   1` on the way up, so they now print `5   8 7 6 5   6 5` on the way down.

---

In this example, nothing will change if `static` keyword is removed from `static D d;`. In `main` function specifically, static local variables are rather pointless.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

If it does not make sense, I usually declare a variable as static. I find static great for scenarios where I might involve counting the origination of such objects.

It depends on the situation, for most cases I always use static to count how many Objects of a particular class was instantiated.

Comment: This neither answers the question nor even appears to understand what the question was asking.